# Why inject interface and not concrete class in Laravel 5.*?

Tags: php, laravel-5, dependency-injection, interface

I'm using laravel 5.* (And also I use Laravel 4) and I can't understand why it's better to inject an interface instead a concrete class.

What are the benefits?

I'm injecting interfaces because I read that it's too much better, but, I can't understand why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this isn't anything Laravel specific, it's just considered best practice in general.

If you inject a concrete class, you have just created a hard dependency.

If you inject an interface, you can use the same code but just inject different classes (example: real DB class for prod, and a Mock DB class for tests) that implements that same interface.

*Actually, you always inject concrete classes, it's just the type hinting that's an interface instead of a concrete class*

Example:

```
class DB implements DBInterface
{
    // A bunch of methods fetching from real DB
}

class MockDB implements DBInterface
{
    // Has the same (interface) methods but returns some fixed data for testing.
}

class Posts
{
    public function __construct(DBInterface $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    
    public function get()
    {
        $this->db->query("....");
    }
}

$posts = new Posts(new DB);
$data  = $posts->get(); // This fetches from the real db

// And for testing
$posts = new Posts(new MockDB);
$data  = $posts->get(); // Fetches from the mock DB instead
```

The power of this is that the class you're injecting will have the same class signature but can have totally different implementations.
Your `Posts`-class doesn't need to care about what implementation it gets...

This is just a quick example, but it explains one, and really good, benefit of using interfaces as type hints...

Comment: Perfect Magnus. That's a really good answer. Of course, I know that I'm injecting a concrete class and type hinting the interface but... I didn't know why type hint the interface and not the concrete class directly.

Thanks!!